# In MySQL using LIKE inside a SELECT case

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am building a view as follows...

```
create view usersAndTickets as 
    select  tickets.subject as 'Name',
            'automatically imported ticket from former support web' as 'Description', 
            case tickets.department_id when 3 then 'Support' when 4 then 'Support' when 5 then 'Feature Request' when 2 then 'Sales' end as 'Type',
            case tickets.priority_id when 1 then 'Low' when 2 then 'Normal' when 3 then 'Urgent' end as 'Severity',
            case tickets.status_id when 1 then 'Under Review' when 2 then 'Closed' when 3 then 'Waiting on Customer' when 4 then 'New' when 7 then 'New' end as 'Status',
            users.email as 'EmailOfUserAssignedTo'
    from custom_fields_values, tickets, users where tickets.staff_id=users.id;
```

In the view, I use CASE WHEN ... specific values to replace numbers with text.

But I also have a case where I do not want to do a strict equality comparison but rather I would like to do sthg like

```
case when custom_fields_values.value like '%Bar%' then 'Acme Product #1' end as 'Product',
case when custom_fields_values.value like '%Foo%' then 'Acme Product #2' end as 'Product',
```

But of course, MySQL complains the 'Product' field already exists.

So how do we use CASE WHEN with matching functions (LIKE) rather than equality?

Comment: `CASE...WHEN...THEN...WHEN...THEN...ELSE...END`

Comment: That didn't work. The parenthesis are required it seems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just want multiple clauses in the `case` expression:

```
(case when custom_fields_values.value like '%Bar%' then 'Acme Product #1' 
      when custom_fields_values.value like '%Foo%' then 'Acme Product #2'
 end) as Product,
```